Why on very old named resolve google.it return different and more dns than new named?
Yesterday I play with old bind on old unix vm (1998, Interactive Unix 4.1.1)
dig www.google.it return this
dig +noedns www.google.it  @192.168.0.15

; <<>> DiG 9.18.30 <<>> +noedns www.google.it @192.168.0.15
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 33534
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 4

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.it.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.it.      4m36s   IN  A   142.251.209.35

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
google.it.      59m35s  IN  NS  ns4.google.com.
google.it.      59m35s  IN  NS  ns1.google.com.
google.it.      59m35s  IN  NS  ns2.google.com.
google.it.      59m35s  IN  NS  ns3.google.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns4.google.com.     1d23h59m35s IN  A   216.239.38.10
ns1.google.com.     1d23h59m35s IN  A   216.239.32.10
ns2.google.com.     1d23h59m35s IN  A   216.239.34.10
ns3.google.com.     1d23h59m35s IN  A   216.239.36.10

;; Query time: 49 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.15#53(192.168.0.15) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue Nov 05 13:34:53 CET 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 202

I try same domain on very latest bind (Rocky Linux 9)
dig +noedns www.google.it  @192.168.0.4

; <<>> DiG 9.18.30 <<>> +noedns www.google.it @192.168.0.4
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 30882
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.it.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.it.      5m  IN  A   142.251.209.35

;; Query time: 326 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.4#53(192.168.0.4) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue Nov 05 13:37:28 CET 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 47

Trying with edns
; <<>> DiG 9.18.30 <<>> www.google.it @192.168.0.4
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 35264
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; COOKIE: 3ef6be6f29a5772001000000672a11a41858b37880b6f84b (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.it.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.it.      4m32s   IN  A   142.251.209.35

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.4#53(192.168.0.4) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue Nov 05 13:37:56 CET 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 86

Why old bind return more results?

You are querying different nameservers. One of them might not have the AUTHORITY data. See also https://serverfault.com/q/1088257
